# Pro*C based batch, Out of Memory?

Tags: c, oracle-pro-c

When trying to compile a Pro*C based batch file, the process "proc" stucks at 100% of 1 CPU core and the memory starts growing to a point where the system needs to OOM kill the process (the machine has 16GB Memory and the process grew up to 9GB).

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

As an aditional information:

-The mk is the one from the instalation of the main package
-The .pc files are the original files (I've tried to compile several, such as dtesys.pc)
-The Libs are correctly compiled
-The environment variables are correctly set

Comment: And what memory usage was expected? Did you run this in another machine? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It's expected not to grow to those values. We're talking about a file that comes with a package made by oracle themselves.
Yes, I've tried to compile the same batch files on a different development environment and it worked perfecly.
This batch is supposed to grab a few tables and write them to a file on the hdd.

Comment: found the problem. It was related to the include of "limits.h" that wasn't on the correct path. I believe that the version that I had, didn't have a define to avoid double includes on the pre-processing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is limits.h because it includes itself recursively on line 123:

```
 /* Get the compiler's limits.h, which defines almost all the ISO constants.
    We put this #include_next outside the double inclusion check because
    it should be possible to include this file more than once and still get
    the definitions from gcc's header.  */
#if defined __GNUC__ && !defined _GCC_LIMITS_H_
/*  `_GCC_LIMITS_H_' is what GCC's file defines.  */
# include_next <limits.h>
#endif
```

So, the solution is to pass parse=none option to Pro*C precompiler:

```
proc parse=none iname=filename.pc oname=filename.c
```

Or, a second option: you may first precompile your source with c precompiler to get pc file:

```
cpp -P -E yourfile.someextension -o yourfile.pc
```

Then you will get limits.h parsed without recursion.

-P option is needed because Pro*C is the program which can be confused with linemarkers.

-E option is needed because Pro*C is the program which can be confused with non-traditional output.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to exclude the problematic header file during the proc stage and include it at the compile stage.

The way to do that is to add to the proc command a flag `define=IN_PROC` and in the pc file wrap the problematic header with:

```
#if !defined(IN_PROC)
#  include <limits.h>
#endif
```

This solved the issue for me